# CMS or framework that offers reseller hosting

Tags: content-management-system, hosting, dns

just doing some preliminary research on a project. do any frameworks like django or ruby on rails offer a way of creating a web app which allows you to sell web hosting to clients and sell domain names? i have looked at sites like hostgator but want to make some more customized.

my clients wouldnt need all the bells and whistles of a normal host and i'd like to maintain some sort of branding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build whatever you want on top of a framework - CMS or otherwise. Ruby on Rails, Symfony, or any one of the other MVC frameworks would let you build a web application that does what you want. You would, of course, need to code it. There'd be integration or construction of a shopping cart, website management, and DNS management involved.

You'd probably have more luck using an application that's already designed for this purpose - a very common one is cPanel (for hosting). For domain names, it's much more complicated, because you need to register with the TLDs. You would probably have better luck reselling for GoDaddy or one of the 100 other sites that sell domain names.

Comment: thank you this is what i was looking for. sorry for the long delay!